# How to capture SQL fired from BusinessObjects Deski

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, business-objects

I am new to BusinessObjects Deski. I was referring few older reports to understand how actually it works.

There is one report where there are multiple Data Providers created and in report body there is a table which is utilizing few fields from multiple Data Providers. I was able to see the exact SQL behind every DP, but while running them individually, I am not getting the same data as per report at BO level. I also tried joining them, still not able to get exact match.

So, my problem here is, I want to capture EXACT SQL which is being fired from report level so that when I run it directly on DB, I get exact same data.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

There are two passes in report generation in BO.

Pass 1 involves creating a SQL statement, sending to a database, and retrieving the result set.  In BO terms the retrieved dataset is called a "microcube".  You can see the contents of the microcubes in the View Data panel.

in Pass 2, the data from one or more microcubes is rendered into the visual form of the report.  This is NOT done with SQL, but using BO's own internal calculation engine -- report/document level filters, formulas, variables, aggregations, etc., all all performed during this pass.

So, the SQL that you are seeing in the data providers is (mostly) identical to what is actually being sent to the underlying databases (if the queries contain prompts, then the prompt text will be replaced with static values).

If you run the SQL from the dataproviders directly in Oracle, the result you get there should match the *microcubes*, but it will not match the presented data in the reports, since Pass 2 is not performed with SQL.